# Enumerating a COM object in C# (converting from PowerShell)

Tags: c#, powershell, com

I'm absolutely new to C# and have very little clue what I'm doing, so appreciate the kid gloves in dealing with my stupidity on the subject.

I have the following working PowerShell code:

```
foreach ($effectivePolicyLinkDn in $effectivePolicyLinks) {
  $effectivePolicyLink = [adsi]("EDMS://"+$effectivePolicyLinkDn)
  $policyObject = [adsi]($effectivePolicyLink.PolicyObjectADsPath)
  foreach ($policyEntry in $policyObject._NewEnum) {
    if ($policyEntry.Type -eq $EDS_APE_TYPE_PV) {

    if (($policyEntry|?{$_.SettingID -eq '40'}).Value -eq 'test-SPNClass') {
      $paramFilter = [xml](($policyEntry|?{$_.SettingID -eq '2'}).Value)
      $possibleValues = $paramFilter.SelectNodes('/PVGRules/PVRuleItem/value/text()') | %{ $_.Value }
    }
    }
  }
}
```

There is a need for me to convert this to C#. The rudimentary code that I have thus far looks something like this:

```
foreach (string effectivePolicyLinkDn in effectivePolicyObjects)
{
    DirectoryEntry effectivePolicyLink = new DirectoryEntry("EDMS://" + effectivePolicyLinkDn);
    DirectoryEntry policyObject = new DirectoryEntry(effectivePolicyLink.InvokeGet("PolicyObjectADsPath").ToString());

    e = (IEnumerator)policyObject.Invoke("_NewEnum");
    while (e.MoveNext())
    {
        //How to get $policyEntry.Type and $policyEntry.SettingID, etc?
        //e.Current does not list these as properties
    }
}
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

EDIT: Still struggling with this; here is an image showing what I'm after:
[image]

Comment: _NewEnum (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms765425(v=vs.85)) is just the old standard COM way of exposing enumerations. In C#, it should just be `foreach(var policyEntry in policyObject)` but it may not work as is. It depends on details. If you have a full reproducing powerShell script we may help more.

Comment: Thank you, @SimonMourier. Note that the working PowerShell code sample does **not** work without using `._NewEnum`. These objects are COM objects. The PowerShell sample as provided **is** fully functional, so I'm not sure if I understand your ask?

Comment: also, if I attempt to for `foreach(var policyEntry in policyObject)`, I get the syntax error `CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'DirectoryEntry' because 'DirectoryEntry' does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator'`.

Comment: I asked for a full reproducing script, something that we can run on our machine, not just an extract of a code, precisely to be able to test how to port the code over.

Comment: The code as listed *is* "complete", however it's not something that you or anyone else would be able to reproduce due to the lack of access to the specific COM objects that I'm referencing. Those objects are made available via a 3rd party commercial application.

Comment: No, it's not complete. If I can't test your code, I can't help you.

Comment: Yes, it is complete. That was the entirety of the code that is relevant to the discussion at hand. As I explained, you would never be able to reproduce it due to its reliance on a 3rd-party proprietary/close-source application that you would never have access to. Thank you for your time, however as you can see I've marked this question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

After much frustration, found the secret sauce that got this to work for me:

```
DirectoryEntry effectivePolicyLink = new DirectoryEntry("EDMS://" + effectivePolicyLinkDn);
var policyAdsPath = effectivePolicyLink.InvokeGet("PolicyObjectADsPath").ToString();
DirectoryEntry policyObject = new DirectoryEntry(policyAdsPath);
e = policyObject.Invoke("_NewEnum") as IEnumerator;
while (e.MoveNext())
{
    var policyEntry = e.Current as dynamic;
}
```

To highight specific change in question:

```
var policyEntry = e.Current as dynamic;
```

Soon as I added that "**as dynamic**", everything started falling in line.